# Intuitive understanding of base shift to orthonomal basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently studying some linear algebra (on my own) and I am a bit stuck on these statements. I can see and follow along how they are derived by using algebra but I have a hard time to truly intuitively understand them, which is annoying :). Any explanation (or links to material) on why these statements holds true would be greatly appreciated.

Suppose that we have a base $B_\vec{u} = (\vec{u_1}, \vec{u_2}, \vec{u_3})$ which is an arbitrary base in the room while $B_\vec{v} = (\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \vec{v_3})$ is an orthonomal base. The base-exchange matrix to the orthonomal base $B_\vec{v}$ is supposed to be easy to determine by using the following formula:

$$\vec{u_1} = (\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{u_1})\vec{v_1}+ (\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{u_1})\vec{v_2}+ (\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{u_1})\vec{v_3}$$

**My analysis of this statement:**
I have a hard time to intuitively grasp this statement, we obviously want to describe $\vec{u_1}$ in terms of $(\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \vec{v_3})$ where the $(\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{u_1})$ represent the coordinate in the $B_\vec{v}$ base. But why does the product of $(\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{u_1})$ represent that coordinate? What does $(\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{u_1})$ actually *mean*?

Comment: In your first statement, you are trying to rewrite the basis vectors $\vec{u_i}$ in terms of the $\vec{v_j}$.  The expression $(\vec{v_j}\cdot \vec{u_i})$ means the usual dot product of vectors. Think instead of the $\vec{v_j}$ as the coordintates, and the $(\vec{v_j}\cdot \vec{u_i})$ as the coefficients on them.

Comment: If $u, v$ are unit vectors, $u\cdot v$ is the length of the orthogonal projection of $v$ on $u$ (or vice versa) in the two dimensional plane defined by $u, v$ -- assuming they are not parallel. In the base change you determine the '$v$ - part' of a vector $u$ this way.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they are really helpful!

Comment: So @Thomas, When you write $\vec{u_1} = (\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{u_1})\vec{v_1}+(\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{u_1})\vec{v_2}+ (\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{u_1})\vec{v_3}$ you get the coefficients by projecting $\vec{u_1}$ onto the vectors $\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \vec{v_3}$. By doing so you get how much "influence" each $\vec{v_x}$ has in the representation of $\vec{u}$?

Comment: This depends on the positon of $u$ relative to the $v_i$. Consider the extreme cases where $u$ coincides with one of the $v_i$ as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in general the orthogonal projection of $\vec{v}$ into the line spanned by a nonzero $\vec{s}$ is the vector

$$\text{proj}_\vec{s}(\vec{v})=\frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{s}}{\vec{s}\cdot\vec{s}}\vec{s},$$

i.e. $\text{proj}_\vec{s}(\vec{v})$ is the vector part of $\vec{v}$ over the span of $\vec{s}$. Therefore if $\vec{s}$ is such that $\left\|\vec{s} \right\|=1$, then $\left\|\vec{s} \right\|^2=\vec{s}\cdot\vec{s}=1$ and

$$\text{proj}_\vec{s}(\vec{v})=\left(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{s}\right)\vec{s}.$$

Now if you have an orthonormal basis, you can represent any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a sum of the projections of that vector into the line spanned by each vector in the basis, because they are mutually orthogonal:

$$\vec{v}=\left(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{s}_1\right)\vec{s}_1+ \cdots + \left(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{s}_n\right)\vec{s}_n$$

where $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\langle \vec{s}_1,\dots,\vec{s}_n\rangle$ is an orthonormal basis.